# "TypeError: integer argument expected, got float" in PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have  program here that I caught on a question here on stack overflow. It's supposed to adjust the constrast of an image, but i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "<module1>", line 20, in <module>
  File "<module1>", line 16, in change_contrast
  File "C:\EduPython\App\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1512, in putpixel
    return self.im.putpixel(xy, value)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

The post is quite old so I don't think the person who wrote it would see my request, so I'm posting here.
Here's the code:

```
from PIL import Image

def change_contrast(img, level):
    def truncate(v):
        return 0 if v < 0 else 255 if v > 255 else v


    img = Image.open("C:\\Users\\omar\\Desktop\\Site\\Images\\obama.png")
    img.load()

    factor = (259 * (level+255)) / (255 * (259-level))
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            color = img.getpixel((x, y))
            new_color = tuple(truncate(factor * (c-128) + 128) for c in color)
            img.putpixel((x, y), new_color)

    return img

result = change_contrast('test_image1.jpg', 128)
result.save('test_image1_output.jpg')
print('done')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, what's `truncate`?

Try saying `int` where you're saying `truncate`.

Comment: truncate is defined right at the beginning after `def change_contrast(img, level) ` as `def truncate(v)`

Comment: factor is a float, so new_color winds up being a tuple of floats. putpixel wants an tuple of ints.

Comment: You need to ensure that new_color is a tuple of ints, not a tuple of floats. Change truncate to make it return an int...or else add int() around the call to truncate().